# How to make a custom compiler warning in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings, bonecp

I am experimenting with [BoneCP](http://jolbox.com) as a connection pooling alternative to DBCP.  I added the `bonecp-0.8.0rc-1.jar` to my runtime classpath, and copy-n-pasted the code from their example page into my test driver:

```
Connection connection = null;
BoneCP connectionPool;
try {
    Class.forName(config.getDatabaseLogger().getJDBCDriver());

    BoneCPConfig boneConfig = configureBoneCP(config);

    connectionPool = new BoneCP(boneConfig);

    connection = connectionPool.getConnection();    // fetch a connection
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

On the line that reads:

```
connectionPool = new BoneCP(boneConfig);
```

Eclipse (Juno) is giving me a compiler warning:

> Resource leak: 'connectionPool' is never closed

It then gives me an option to "*Add @SuppressWarnings 'resource' to newConnectionManager*" (`newConnectionManager()` references the class this is contained in).

**How is this possible?** How does Eclipse know anything about a `BoneCP` object, and how does it know that it must be closed? Is this some kind of "custom warning" that ships with the BoneCP library? If so, how could I add/annotate code to my own projects to help warn downstream developers that they aren't using my libraries correctly?

Comment: Do you have the Javadoc for BoneCp ?

Comment: I've did the same thing but I cannot reproduce it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is caused by this statement:

```
connection = connectionPool.getConnection();
```

The method `getConnection()` returns a object of type [java.sql.Connection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html) which implements [java.lang.AutoCloseable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) since Java 7. Eclipse generates this warning when it can not determine whether a resource which implements either `java.io.Closeable` or `java.lang.AutoCloseable` gets closed by all possible code paths.

Answer (score 1):

```
How does Eclipse know anything about a BoneCP object, 
                                  and how does it know that it must be closed?
```

[Docs of eclipse says](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-avoiding_resource_leaks.htm)

> > Classes implementing the interface java.io.Closeable (since JDK 1.5) and java.lang.AutoCloseable (since JDK 1.7) are considered to represent external resources, which should be closed using method close(), when they are no longer needed.
>
> The Eclipse Java compiler is able to analyze whether code using such types adheres to this policy.
>
> objects do not directly represent an operating system resource. If the wrapped resource is closed, the wrapper doesn't need closing. Conversely, if a wrapper is closed this will include closing of the wrapped resource. The analysis has a second white list for detecting wrapper resources, and will recognize whether the underlying actual resource will be closed directly or indirectly via the wrapper. Either one suffices to silence warnings regarding resource leaks. **The white list contains classes from java.io**, java.util.zip, java.security, java.beans and java.sound.sampled.

Your BoneCP classe implements the interface **java.io.Serializable** ,this might be the reason.

Comment: [BoneCP](http://jolbox.com/bonecp/downloads/site/apidocs/com/jolbox/bonecp/BoneCP.html) didn't implements those interfaces.

Comment: But [BoneCP](http://jolbox.com/bonecp/downloads/site/apidocs/index.html) doesn't implement either of them ?

Comment: what about `Connection`  interface  ???It has a method close()..how about that  ???

Comment: ...but the warning is on the `BoneCP` instance (the connection pool), not the `java.sql.Connection` instance!

Comment: @Baadshah Read the following line there : *If a method returns a resource to its caller, it is not responsible for closing; **no problem is reported.*** :)

Comment: Edited my post with possible reason.Please feel free to edit or even vote to delete if you think this is not case OP is facing the issue.

Comment: @Baadshah You mean to say if a class implements `Serializable` , then it can potentially give this sort of warning ?

Comment: I understood in such way from that last paragraph..let me know if i am wrong . :)